# Passing a array or passing a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

The function GetCallRef(...) expect a pointer to a buffer for this 3rd parameter i.e. call_id is my pointer. However, I don't know the length of the string that will be returned in the call_id. This call_id will only be used in this function, so will only have local scope so I will be only using the call_id returned in my function.

So my question would be; is it ok to declare a pointer and pass that.

```
char *call_id = NULL;
```

Or would be be better to declare an array of a very large size (as I don't know big is big enough)

```
char call_id[1024]
```

The actual function.

```
if(GetCallRef(crn, GET_CALLID, call_id) == 0) {
    /* use the call id - not used outside of this function */
}
```

I don't have the source code for the actual function `GetCallRef(...)` because it is closed.

I guess the buffer will be better as the function internally may copy directly into that buffer. However, as arrays decay into pointers in function arguments and I am not passing the size as it is not part of this function signature, it will be just 4 bytes in length. How does the function know how big my array is? It cannot.

If I pass a pointer it can assign the address of where the string value is stored i.e. and return that.

```
call_id = call_reference_id;
```

All the document says that the buffer should be big enough to store the call id, but it doesn't say how big it should be.

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: Doesn't the documentation say what is the max size of the call_id?

Comment: No, it just says that the buffer should be big enough. How sad is that?

Comment: You cannot "pass an array" in C -- a function cannot have a parameter of array type.

Comment: Also, if you passed an uninitialized or NULL pointer, it would be completely pointless. C is always pass-by-value. What's the point of passing a value that cannot be used?

Comment: "If I pass a pointer it can assign the address of where the string value is stored i.e. and return that." What? That doesn't make any sense. It can assign to it or do whatever it wants. It's a local variable. But it has no effect on outside code. It can return it, but you're not using the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the documentation says *"buffer should be big enough to store the call id"*, it means that the function expects the caller to pass a pre-allocated buffer be it on stack or heap.

> **The important Q is how much memory should be allocated to the passed buffer?**

The documentation of the function should mention this!
There is no way to be 100% safe without the function telling you this information.
Perhaps you need to check some other api which takes similar parameter or check functional spec which documents this.

Your last option if everything fails is to allocate an array of a big enough size, perhaps `1024` and test the code rigorously.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely pass an array in this case.  If the docs say the function wants a buffer, then just passing a pointer will likely cause a segfault.  If it doesn't give any indication of how big 'big enough' is, then that's poor documentation.  If you know what sort of strings `call_id` is likely to be, then you can guess a suitable size buffer to create.  If not, are you able to test the function and see what sort of values it does return?  That may give enough of an idea to work from.

Try using an array with plenty of space (a size of 1024 like you suggest seems like a good starting point), and see what it returns as a `call_id`.  Do this many times.  You may find it is always a 64 character string, for example, in which case you can then just pass it an array with at least 64 elements and should be fine.

Comment: you cannot "pass an array" in C -- a function cannot have a parameter of array type

Comment: Sure you can.  I can define a function as `int foo (char bar[]) {...}` just fine, and passing a normal pointer to it won't actually work.  The mechanics under the hood will still be using a pointer, but a function can indeed have a parameter of array type.  More importantly, what I meant by this answer was that there should be an actual array at the end of the pointer that OP passes to the function.

Comment: OK I just checked, and the bit about passing a normal pointer not working is incorrect.  But the main point is still true, and more importantly, I can easily 'pass an array': `int a[3]={...}; foo (a);` works just fine if `foo` expects an `int` pointer.

Comment: Right but that's because the array gets implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element, since the function takes a pointer. The point is, no matter what, the function he's calling takes a pointer. The only question is what the pointer points to.